# Generate View at server side using javascript lib

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JavaScript lib that creates table, its [Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/) and i am adding it with jquery, that means along with my html i will send the script that generates this table, and then it will be generated on client side.

So my question is:

1. Is this bad?
2. How to send the already generated html along with the script?

I am using aspx razor syntax

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily bad. As long as the data that your sending is nothing that needs to be kept secret (database usernames, passwords, etc.). The rendering of the table would need to be controlled so that it doesn't slow down the rendering of the page, especially if it is a large table.